# Automate SSH scripting to join nodes on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, automation

I have a of machines to join nodes to in a Kubernetes cluster.
I was able to create a script to automate the installation of Kubernetes on baremetal from scratch, but I need help to create a script to join the machines on the different nodes. I don't know how to copy and paste in a shell script.

Here's what I would like to automate (pseudo code)

```
log in as root
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
Results = kubeadm join <token>
Copy Results
ssh hostname1
log in as root 
(paste Results)
exit
exit
ssh hostname2
log in as root 
(paste Results)
exit
exit
...
...
...
.
```

Comment: Rancher. Creates one liners. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

use ansible for that .
get join token
inventory:

```
machine1
machine2
machine3
```

and launch a playbook :

```
- hosts: all 
  tasks: 
  - name: script launch 
    script: ton_scrip.sh
```